# Save/Load Form Input Values in Web App

Tags: jquery, database, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I'm developing an app which is practically a glorified calculator. I need this app to be able to save values to a client-side db (located on users device) on user request and then be able to load a saved calculation and input any specific set of saved values back into the form.

I've looked for answers but have really only found tutorials/walkthroughs pertaining to submitting forms in apps and passing the input values but nothing about how to do so and store/recover multiple entries. These are a couple sites I've used to get a basic understanding.:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery-mobile-forms/

and

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ch05_id35816678.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm currently using jquery mobile, developing/testing as a web app, and compiling into android and ios native apps using phonegap.

Comment: How much data do you need to save client side?  If it's not that much, you can just use cookies.

Comment: If you're already using phonegap, have you looked at the storage api? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: I took a look at the storage API but don't know how exactly to implement it to save the form input values and then recover them on user's request?

@Ivan: I'm only looking at being able to save/load in packets of about 5kb, so not much. How would I go about using cookies to save the form input values and hten recover them on user's request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Chrome has a 4kb limit on the size of a cookie, I'd go with HTML 5's localStorage.  However, if the size of the cookie will be less than 4kb, then I'd go with cookies since they are more likely to be supported.  I'll list a few options you can use:

### Option 1: Cookies

If you want to use cookies with jQuery, you'll need this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie.

Then you can set cookies like so:

```
$.cookie("key", "value");
```

Then, if we want to get the cookie, we simply type:

```
$.cookie("key");
```

For more info on how to get and set cookies, check [this blog post](http://collegesnippets.blogspot.com/2012/01/jquery-cookies.html) (I wrote the blog post to be fair).

### Option 2: HTML5 Local Storage

If the mobile browser supports local storage, then you can use it to store more than 5kb of data.

In order to use local storage, you simply use it like any other object in Javascript:

```
if(localstorage.data) {
  // Do something with localstorage.data
} else {
  // Set localstorage.data
}
```

### Option 3: Cookies and Server Side Data

Option 3 is the safest bet.  Create a session cookie on the client side and associate the data with the session cookie on the server side.

While this isn't what you want (since you wanted the data on the client side), it would give you the most flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan!

I'm going to use local storage and JSON to store/retrieve the data as strings with uniqueIDs.

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as the correct one to help others who have the same problem as you find the correct answer. :)